# Fastest way to get the results in a big DB using python API - Elasticsearch

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch, nosql

I am trying to read around 1 million documents.
I am using the *Scan API*, but it takes around 30 seconds which is too slow for me.

Is there a faster way?

The query I am using is a standard `match_all` query.
In addition, the max result window is 1000000.

Comment: scroll API is probably the most efficient method there is. Do you have an idea where the bottleneck is? To answer this question you might want to consider: How many machines are in your cluster? How much disk space do these 1M documents occupy? Is the CPU being used by 100%? How broad is the network between ES cluster and the client?

Comment: I am not sure it is a bottleneck to be honest. I have many duplicates in my DB so i am just scrolling through all the documents to find them. Maybe there is a faster way to do it ?

Comment: You could try [sliced scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll) which allows to do the scroll in several parallel processes. As far as I can see there is no parameter for sliced scroll in the [python elasticsearch docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) so you might have to construct HTTP requests manually. The bottleneck however may be reading from disk, or network bandwidth, or anything else. (Bottleneck == the thing that limits the performance the most.)